# React Native on Samsung Tab A is slow

Tags: react-native

I am currently developing an application in React Native. There is significant performance drop when I run it on a Samsung Tab A (buttons visibly lag when clicked, a 3D animation we have takes very long to load in, etc.) I tried running the same application on a OnePlus 6T, and all these performance issues are gone. Obviously, the specs are better on a 6T vs. the Tab A, but why would tasks like button clicks even lag? This makes me wonder if the Tab A can support React Native apps at all. Does anyone have experience developing on the Tab A with React Native and have any advice?

Comment: Did you check what else was open / running on the tab A?  If you had 10 apps and Chrome with 5 tabs it could be starved for RAM and other apps could be stealing CPU in the background

Comment: It is a development tablet, so there is basically never anything running except for the app I am working on. I just checked the memory usage though, and it does seem that internal background processes take like 1/3 of the RAM. This seems like an almost unfixable situation though.

Comment: have you tried running using Hermes?

Comment: Woah, Hermes looks exactly like what I need. Thank you so much!